# Why RISC-V CRC algorithm fails on verify_image?

Tags: linux, image, riscv, openocd, risc

I have a CVA6 design implemented to FPGA, I have connected the OpenOCD and after writing the image to RAM, I tried to verify it.
But the verification fails and I get this message

```
verify_image uImage 0x80200000
Algorithm timed out after 180001 ms.
ra = 0x0
sp = 0x0
gp = 0x0
tp = 0x0
t0 = 0x0
t1 = 0x0
t2 = 0x0
s0 = 0x0
s1 = 0x0
a0 = 0x80200000
a1 = 0x82cb3e
a2 = 0x0
a3 = 0x0
a4 = 0x0
a5 = 0x0
a6 = 0x0
a7 = 0x0
s2 = 0x0
s3 = 0x0
s4 = 0x0
s5 = 0x0
s6 = 0x0
s7 = 0x0
s8 = 0x0
s9 = 0x0
s10 = 0x0
s11 = 0x0
t3 = 0x0
t4 = 0x0
t5 = 0x0
t6 = 0x0
pc = 0x80200040
mstatus = 0xa00001800
mepc = 0x80200040
mcause = 0xc
error executing RISC-V CRC algorithm
verified 8571710 bytes in 283.027466s (29.576 KiB/s)
```

The PC stucks at 0x80200040 address, the entry point and load address are 0x80200000,
mcause = 0xc means Instruction page fault, but sometimes it shows mcause = 0x2 (Illegal instruction). Also I dump the 0x80200000 area and use objdump to see if there is some valid code there and I got this

```
Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
       0:   56190527            0x56190527
       4:   f842                    fsw fa6,48(sp)
       6:   f7a1                    bnez    a5,0xffffffffffffff4e
       8:   0765                    addi    a4,a4,25
       a:   98003957            0x98003957
       e:   c1ad                    beqz    a1,0x70
      10:   2080                    fld fs0,0(s1)
      12:   0000                    unimp
      14:   2080                    fld fs0,0(s1)
      16:   0000                    unimp
      18:   d4c1                    beqz    s1,0xffffffffffffffa0
      1a:   07ca                    slli    a5,a5,0x12
      1c:   1a05                    addi    s4,s4,-31
      1e:   0102                    c.slli64    sp
      20:   34365643            0x34365643
      24:   3641                    jal 0xfffffffffffffba4
      26:   694c                    flw fa1,20(a0)
      28:   756e                    flw fa0,248(sp)
      2a:   0078                    addi    a4,sp,12
    ...
      40:   8b1f 0808 5738          0x573808088b1f
      46:   03026507            0x3026507
      4a:   6d49                    lui s10,0x12
      4c:   6761                    lui a4,0x18
      4e:   0065                    c.nop   25
      50:   59ec                    lw  a1,116(a1)
      52:   d713547b            0xd713547b
      56:   dfba                    sw  a4,252(sp)
```

As you can see at 0x40 it doesn't look like instruction.
Why does this happen?

I tried to verify the image with `verify_image uImage 0x80200000`. It was not verified, and this is strange because I used [cva6-sdk](https://github.com/openhwgroup/cva6-sdk) to produce the image.

Comment: None of that looks like code, the value at 0, at 0xa, 0x12, and what does disassemble doesn't make any sense as RISC V code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was due to wrong base address in openOCD config file. So I managed to fix it.